# If I do a GROUP BY function with multiple fields, will the select only show rows where all fields in the GROUP BY exactly match?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

For an example, if I did this:

```
  SELECT il.itm, il.price, il.strt_dt, il.exp_dt, pl.itm_cd
    FROM itm_list il,
         prc_list pl
   WHERE il.prc_cd = pl.prc_cd
GROUP BY il.itm, il.price, il.strt_dt, il.exp_dt, pl.itm_cd
```

Would the select only group rows where those fields are *exactly* the same in all 5 rows? As in, it will remove all duplicate rows but keep any unique combination of those rows?

So if I had the select return:

```
il.itm ----- il.price ----- il.strt_dt ----- il.exp_dt ----- pl.itm_cd
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
BANANA       $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2013        177
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
APPLE        $2             1/1/2012         1/1/2013        191
```

Would the results return Result A... (every row with some kind of uniqueness between all 5 columns)

```
il.itm ----- il.price ----- il.strt_dt ----- il.exp_dt ----- pl.itm_cd
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
BANANA       $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2013        177
APPLE        $2             1/1/2012         1/1/2013        191
```

OR Result B?... (if they group on one column, then there will only be one entry)

```
il.itm ----- il.price ----- il.strt_dt ----- il.exp_dt ----- pl.itm_cd
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
BANANA       $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2013        177
```

Comment: an aggregate function is not being used..which should be the case

Comment: Why don't you run the query and see what the results are?

Comment: GROUP BY is typically combined with aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, COUNT, SUM). Instead of what you do now you can do SELECT DISTINCT without the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would give Result A.

```
Group By X, Y means put all those with the same values for both X and Y in the one group.
```

So for your case, combination of all the five columns having unique value collectively will be considered correct.

Therefore,all the possible combinations of `il.itm ----- il.price ----- il.strt_dt ----- il.exp_dt ----- pl.itm_cd` having unique values will be the result.

For example for the record

```
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
```

Each record having exactly the same value for the five columns would be group along with it.

If we change any value of column say `price = $10`, then the record will become unique since it has differing value from the above five fields combined, and hence will be considered another unique record.

Hence the answer: **Result 1**

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISTINCT function like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT  il.itm, il.price, il.strt_dt, il.exp_dt, pl.itm_cd
    FROM itm_list il,
         prc_list pl
   WHERE il.prc_cd = pl.prc_cd
```

Comment: nit: `DISTINCT` isn't really a function.

Comment: This won't be any different to the `group by` solution (and distinct is not a "function")

Answer (score 0):

it would be Result A

but i would say why don't you just try it as that's the quickest way to learn these things

Comment: right and its better to try with a more simple table. Just create a minimal table for example `create table threed (x int, y int, z int);` and fill in some coordinates that duplicate on x and y or so. It does not make much sense to group by all columns of a table!

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY x, y, z` means: give me one result record per x-y-z combination.

So you get Result A, because

```
APPLE        $1             1/1/2011         1/1/2012        191
APPLE        $2             1/1/2012         1/1/2013        191
```

obviously differ in the columns you stated in GROUP BY.

To get one record per itm as in Result B, group by itm only, thus saying: give me one record per itm. Of course you'd have to specify then which price etc. to show. The minimum price for the itm? Or the avarage price?

So you use GROUP BY ____ to say: give me one record *per* _____. For all other columns you specify an aggregate function, such as MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT. E.g. `AVG(il.price)`.